# zend controller can't specify layout

Tags: zend-framework

I have this code

```
class PagamentoController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $model_pagamenti = new Model_Pagamento();
        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('/crudabstract/index.phtml');
        $this->view->render('/crudabstract/index.phtml');
    }
...
```

and when i run /pagamento/index

i get this error

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: script 'pagamento/index.phtml' not found in path (C:/www/www/abc/application/views\scripts/)
Stack trace:
```

why won't it work ? it's not supposed to be looking for **"pagamento/index.phtml"**, but for **"/crudabstract/index.phtml"**

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out how in my own code

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('crudabstract/'.$this->_request->getActionName(), null, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message states that there is no view script defined for the index action. when you define a controller, zend framework will automatically look for a corresponding view file which is not being found in your case. so create a corresponding view file in

```
application/views/script/pagamento/index.phtml
```

and it should work.